# Is there a general standard for servo actuators?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces

It is said in the standard AS94900 that the standard ARP490 should be considered for the actuators of the control surfaces in the aircraft. However, this standard is on servo valves and not servo actuators. is there a specific standard for servo actuators in aviation? or the servo valve of the servo actuator should be tested separately?